# Creating rounded corners in IE7 / IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, rounded-corners

I am creating a rounded corners tabs, that works fine in IE9, Mozilla and Chrome, but not in IE7/IE8.

Here is the code:

```html
<div id="navbar">
<div id="holder">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
<li><a href="#">News</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

```css
#navbar {}
#holder {
border-bottom:1px solid #000;
overflow:hidden;
}

#navbar #holder ul {
margin:0;
padding:0;
list-style:none;
margin-top:15px;
}

#navbar #holder ul li { }
#navbar #holder ul li a {
text-decoration:none;
float:left;
margin-right:5px;
border:1px solid #000;
padding:15px;
text-align:center;
width:90px;
border-bottom:none;
display:block;
behavior:url(border-radius.htc);
border-radius:5px 5px 0 0;
}

#navbar #holder ul li a:hover {
background:#C09;
color:#fff;
}
```

Can you please let me know the code so that it works for IE7/IE8 as well?

Comment: I've always kind of liked Spiffy Corners: http://www.spiffycorners.com/

Comment: AFAIK IE7 and IE8 doesn't support rounded corners

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the border-radius.htc. Or better still, don't use one. I have found more often then not, .htc files prove to be more trouble then helpful. You can try this jquery plug in...http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IE 7/8 do not support `border-radius`. I hear IE9 does though.

This site contains a hack for getting rounded borders in IE7/8 though: http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/ . You'll need to download border-radius.htc and put the following code in your CSS:

```
.rounded-corners {
  behavior: url(http://yoursite.com/border-radius.htc);
}
```

Comment: ie-8 and 7 supporting border radius via javascript check this link working border radius in ie7-ie8
http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners

Comment: If I have a opacity anything less than 100%, the background image becomes boxes and not plain. Is that an issue?

Answer (score 8):

Use jquery corner , it will work on all major browser

http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

You can even configure the corners the way you like!!

Comment: Works great except the rounded corner cutoff background needs to be transparent. For me it's a light blue color which doesn't go with my background image

Answer (score 5):

There are following solutions :

1. CSSPie (http://css3pie.com/ but its compressed js file is 40 KB in size)
2. There is another solution using htc file for IE

   ```
       behavior: url(http://yoursite.com/border-radius.htc);
            (almost 40 KB of size)
   ```

   The guide can be found here http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/
3. Another solution that I personally recommend is :

   ```
        jquery.corner.js (http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/)
   ```

   It's uncompressed js file is 10 KB in size.

Comment: I have tried every solution and the only one that creates border-radius equals modern browsers is CSSPie, all the other options has it issues. The only bad thing in CSSPie is that it make IE8 very slow

Answer (score 2):

border radius supported ie-7, ie-8, ie-9 via javascript check this tutorial how to show border radius in ie http://davidwalsh.name/css-rounded-corners

Answer (score 0):

**The Internet Explorer supports the CSS** `border-radius` **property natively not until version 9.** For lower version of IE, check the jQuery plugin kvijayhari mentioned, [jQuery Corner](http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/).