# Border radius not supporting in IE7

Tags: html, border, css

i know border-radius property wont support in **IE7**.

Is there any css tricks to do border-radius in `IE7` browsers.

Comment: Google your *exact* question title. You will get results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating rounded corners in IE7 / IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941158/creating-rounded-corners-in-ie7-ie8)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [CSS3 PIE](http://css3pie.com/) to get this working.

To get it add the pie.htc file to the ROOT of your site. In your CSS file where you want to use border-radius add the following code:

```
behavior: url(path/to/PIE.htc);
```

In normal CSS the url is relative to the CSS file. For htc files it is relative to the ROOT of your website. This is important as it won't work otherwise. Blame Microsoft.

**NOTE:**

If it's not working still then add this to your selectors:

```
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of "tricks" to get rounded corners in browsers that do not support the "border-radius" CSS property. Just do a google search for "rounded corners css". [This one](http://jonraasch.com/blog/css-rounded-corners-in-all-browsers) seems promising for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, IE 9 and 10 are the only versions of IE that support border-radius. IE 8 and below do not support border-radius.

Check this http://css3pie.com/

Answer (score 1):

**use make a curve border .ping image in photoshop and use it .....because border-radius-bottomleft ,border-radius-bottom right etc not work on ie6-8....**

**use that code for border-radius working well ....**

**

```
background-color: #E8EDEF;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 78px;
    width: 591px;
behavior: url(pie/PIE.htc);
```

**

**and also see for border-radius http://css3pie.com/**

**given in detail in document**