# rounded tab corner using MVC and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

In the jQuery tabs example in http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/, the tab corners are not rounded in IE7. How can we make them rounded in IE7? Where to get the complete code for these examples? Apparently the actual css files used are missing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating rounded corners in IE7 / IE8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941158/creating-rounded-corners-in-ie7-ie8)

Answer (score 3):

You would have to use a javascript hack in IE7, as it doesn't support `border-radius` in CSS.

See [Creating rounded corners in IE7 / IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941158/creating-rounded-corners-in-ie7-ie8) for a few options.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: You can't. IE7 (and 8) doesn't support what you're trying to do. http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius

The slightly longer answer: You might be able to fake it: http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/